# How can I subtract two values selected from a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table, like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ladderStandard` (
  `charId` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `poeRank` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `lvl` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `exp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ladderTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


INSERT INTO `ladderStandard` (`charId`, `poeRank`, `lvl`, `exp`, `ladderTime`) VALUES
(10000, 10000, 91, 2108226870, '2015-02-06 23:37:11'),
(10001, 10001, 91, 2108221545, '2015-02-06 23:37:11'),
(10002, 10002, 91, 2108219833, '2015-02-06 23:37:11'),
(10003, 10003, 91, 2108192924, '2015-02-06 23:37:11'),
(10004, 10004, 91, 2108154502, '2015-02-06 23:37:11'),
(10005, 10005, 91, 2108153763, '2015-02-06 23:37:11'),
(10000, 9998, 91, 2108226870, '2015-02-06 23:58:21'),
(10001, 9999, 91, 2108221545, '2015-02-06 23:58:21'),
(10002, 10000, 91, 2108219833, '2015-02-06 23:58:21'),
(10003, 10001, 91, 2108192924, '2015-02-06 23:58:21'),
(10004, 10002, 91, 2108154502, '2015-02-06 23:58:21'),
(10005, 10003, 91, 2108153763, '2015-02-06 23:58:21'),
```

I have two queries:

```sql
SELECT charId, exp FROM ladderStandard WHERE ladderTime = '2015-02-06 23:37:11';
SELECT charId, exp FROM ladderStandard WHERE ladderTime = '2015-02-06 23:58:21';
```

Now I want subtract these two queries to get `charId` and `exp.from.first.query` - `exp.from.second.query`

Here is an example on [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2de71/6).

Answer (score 0):

You need to join both the queries then do the math

```
SELECT a.charid,
       a.exp - b.exp
FROM   (SELECT charId,
               exp
        FROM   ladderStandard
        WHERE  ladderTime = '2015-02-06 23:37:11') a
       JOIN (SELECT charId,
                    exp
             FROM   ladderStandard
             WHERE  ladderTime = '2015-02-06 23:58:21') b
         ON a.charid = b.charid
```

[**SqlFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2de71/8)

Answer (score 0):

Use a self-JOIN. The `WHERE` clause will restrict each subset of the table to the specific time, and the `ON` clause links the corresponding rows.

```
SELECT a.charid, a.exp - b.exp AS diff
FROM ladderStandard AS a
JOIN ladderStandard AS b ON a.charid = b.charid
WHERE a.ladderTime = '2015-02-06 23:37:11'
AND b.ladderTime = '2015-02-06 23:58:21'
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2de71/10)

Comment: Hi sir.. just a small clarification. Thought of suggesting this answer. Which one will have better performance. I am filtering the records before joining. Is that the same here

Comment: See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2de71/13 for the different EXPLAIN outputs. And http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9244a8/1 for if you add indexes on the columns being used in `WHERE` and `ON`.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample data, the `exp` values are the same for the same ID in both groups. So subtracting one from the other will just result in zero.

However, on the assumption that your actual data has different values, here is a way to perform the operation without joining the table.

```
SELECT  CharId,
        Sum( case LadderTime
             when :SecondDate then exp
             else -exp end )as SumExp
FROM    LadderStandard
where   LadderTime in( :FirstDate, :SecondDate )
group by CharID;
```

As expected, this <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2de71/17/0)</kbd> shows all zeros except for `CharID` = 10291, which has an entry in the second group but not the first. In that case, the calculation is `0 - exp.from.second.query` which is just the negative of the `exp` value.

Comment: Example from Fiddle works... but it's not what I need, because In full table I have for each CharId hundreds timestamps. I want subtract only two of them at the time. This what you show here is little different but It's doesnt work or I don't understand somethings, correct me if I'm worng, instead of :FirstDate and :Secondate should I place my tmiestamps like `'2015-02-06 23:37:11'`

Comment: In the Fiddle, I hard-coded the time value. But in the query shown above, I assumed you would have stored the two dates of interest in variables so that's how I wrote it. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2de71/20/0 for an example using variables. And, btw, if the solution you are looking for depends on other criteria, please state those in the original question.